# ssh tunel how to?

Tags: ssh, scp, ssh-tunneling

ok I have a following situation. machine1 , machine2 and laptop. I need ssh and scp protocol enabled such that I can access to machine1 and do some things there. also i cannot access to machine2 directly but only through machine1. Sometimes i need to scp stuff from and to machine2 from my laptop and to do that i need to scp it to machine1 and then from machine1 to machine2. is there a way to do this directly. I how should I setup/configure this? (examples are more than welcomed). all machines run on linux (different flavours laptop-ubuntu, machine1-debian, machine2-centos)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

start this on laptop:

```
ssh machine1 -L 2222:machine2:22
```

where `machine2` is the address of machine2 as seen from machine1

then in another shell on laptop

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

or

```
scp -P 2222  127.0.0.1:filename  etc...
```

note: scp uses capital P , ssh uses small p